# How to run a win32 console application on Linux/Apache web-hosting?

Tags: php, c++, linux, apache, winapi

The executable uses 2 un-managed dlls & gives output on console.
I'm currently running it on XAMPP/localhost (on my PC) & grabbing the console output with PHP's Exec()/PassThru() function.

Will it run the same way on a typical Apache/Linux based Web-hosting account? If not , what can I do?

In PHP :

```
<?php
exec("TradeLogin.exe",$output);
//TradeLogin.exe is the win32-console-app, 
//situated at Xampp/htdocs, with couple of supporting binary files & dlls 
//(compiled on Visual-Studio-2015)
echo $output[0]."<br/>";
echo $output[1]."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Why would you expect a Windows executable to run on Linux?

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell if there will be permission problems with it (I'm on a Windows atm. so can't try.)

If you want it to run this way, you need a Windows emulator (like Wine for example), and use it like

```
exec("wine TradeLogin.exe 2>&1",$output);
```

Or full path may be necessary. Note that the execution of the PHP code will stop until your program has finished running.